# can i set expire headers for js, images and css using javascript instead of apache configuration?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers

I read about expire headers to enhance performance of web site, all my search says it is only possible using apache configuration. Is there any way to do it with javascript?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the **client**.
HTTP headers are sent along with the resources from the server.

Unless you write a Node.js server, you can't do that.